# Enqueue style not loading css only

Tags: wordpress

The following code is not working and I'm just a WordPress newbie trying to implement a custom WordPress theme from an already exsisting one, here's the code I wrote in the index.php file at the top of it, this snippet it's supposed to load the stylesheets of the original template into the wordpress one, I've tried watching some tutorials and consult some resources on the web yet I couldn't find any specific answer why this code is not working, it's just giving an html without styling WordPress page.

```
<?php
// wp_register_style() example 
wp_register_style(
    'bootstrap', // handle name 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/plugins-css.css', // the URL of the stylesheet 
    array(), // an array of dependent styles
  '1.0', // version number 
    true, // CSS media type 
);

wp_register_style(
    'bootstrap_0', // handle name 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/revolution/css/settings.css', // the URL of the stylesheet 
    array(), // an array of dependent styles
  '1.0', // version number 
    true, // CSS media type 
);

wp_register_style(
    'bootstrap_1', // handle name 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/typography.css', // the URL of the stylesheet 
    array(), // an array of dependent styles
  '1.0', // version number 
    true, // CSS media type 
);

wp_register_style(
    'bootstrap_2', // handle name 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/shortcodes/shortcodes.css', // the URL of the stylesheet 
    array(), // an array of dependent styles
  '1.0', // version number 
    true, // CSS media type 
);

wp_register_style(
    'bootstrap_3', // handle name 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', // the URL of the stylesheet 
    array(), // an array of dependent styles
  '1.0', // version number 
    true, // CSS media type 
);

wp_register_style(
    'bootstrap_4', // handle name 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css', // the URL of the stylesheet 
    array(), // an array of dependent styles
    '1.0', // version number 
    true, // CSS media type 
);

function load_styles(){
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_0' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_1' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_2' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_3' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_4' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_styles');
wp_head();
?>
```

I'd really appreciate some help, thank you.

Comment: register/enqueue should exist in the callback of `wp_enqueue_scripts`

Comment: What do you mean? Could you provide me an example?

Comment: If you do `View Source` in your browser, what do you see?

Comment: I see the source code of the page, is loading it, yet is not loading the css even if I put the wp_register_style functions inside the load_styles function.

Comment: Now it's loading only html.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it including this inside the html head tag, thanks for your support guys:

```
<?php
// wp_register_style() example 
wp_register_style(
    'bootstrap', // handle name 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/plugins-css.css', // the URL of the stylesheet 
    array(), // an array of dependent styles
  '1.0', // version number 
    'all',
);

wp_register_style(
    'bootstrap_0', // handle name 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/revolution/css/settings.css', // the URL of the stylesheet 
    array(), // an array of dependent styles
  '1.0', // version number 
    'all',
);

wp_register_style(
    'bootstrap_1', // handle name 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/typography.css', // the URL of the stylesheet 
    array(), // an array of dependent styles
  '1.0', // version number 
    'all',
);

wp_register_style(
    'bootstrap_2', // handle name 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/shortcodes/shortcodes.css', // the URL of the stylesheet 
    array(), // an array of dependent styles
  '1.0', // version number 
    'all',
);

wp_register_style(
    'bootstrap_3', // handle name 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', // the URL of the stylesheet 
    array(), // an array of dependent styles
  '1.0', // version number 
    'all',
);

wp_register_style(
    'bootstrap_4', // handle name 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css', // the URL of the stylesheet 
    array(), // an array of dependent styles
    '1.0', // version number 
    'all',
);

function load_styles(){
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri());
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_0' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_1' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_2' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_3' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_4' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_styles');
wp_head();
?>
```